# using proguard-retrace 7.0.0 not able to deobfuscate the line numbers

Tags: java, android, proguard, deobfuscation

i am using proguard-retrace 7.0.0 version in my java project but i am not able to obfuscate the line numbers class and method name are working fine, Also is there any way to deobfuscate the lambda menthds as well?

i have tried different versions but facing similar issue.

Comment: What `-keepattributes` are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.